# Put a period of 1 hours between 2 dot on Amchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amcharts

I try to define the period between 2 dot using the library [amChart](https://www.amcharts.com) so I use the parameter [minPeriod](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxis#minPeriod) like this :

```
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "hh",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
},
```

But amChart just continue to like if nothing change. No idea why. Is there a conflit with other parameter?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Post a fiddle with your code and data that shows what exactly is the problem.